The array modifier isn't affecting the curve modifier, causing an offset
The array modifier isn't interacting with the curve modifier, resulting in an offset. It's not aligning with the curve.

the view looks different in edit and object mode

in object mode it looks like this.


What have you tried already? It's a bit easier to solve your issue if you show us more of what is actually going on, what your modifier settings are, what you're aiming for etc.

@Jakemoyo "I'm following this tutorial and have followed all the steps exactly as shown."https://youtu.be/OhzcCsR_EO0?si=q5qKON55qD2W3PIx

Make sure that the location of the object is the same as the location of the curve, if it doesn't solve your problem please share your file

@moonboots its working , Thank you for considering my request

Make sure that the location of the object is the same as the location of the curve. To do that you can select your curve, press ShiftS > Cursor to Selected, then select your object and ShiftS > Selection to Cursor.
